# How to run scripts based on solution configuration in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, project.json

I have the following script in my `project.json` file which I am using to build my class library project into a NuGet package. I don't want to build any Debug NuGet packages. How can I limit this script to only run when the solution configuration is set to Release mode to speed up the build time in debug mode?

Alternatively, as a matter of curiosity, how can I pass the solution configuration into the command below so that 'Release' is not hard coded.

```
"scripts": {
  "postcompile": [
    "dotnet pack --no-build --configuration Release"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `%compile:Configuration%` to get the current Configuration. [Here](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/0f573ed04b0d90ecfc8570d2852d15a58dd7f09a/src/dotnet/commands/dotnet-compile/ManagedCompiler.cs#L167-L190) is the list of variables available to `precompile` and `postcompile` scripts.

Comment: Where can we find the complete list of variables available for these script events?

Answer (score 5):

To actually limit the creation of the nuget package based on the configuration, you'll need to pass it into a script, like this makeNuget.cmd file which I store at the root of my project:

```
@Echo off
IF "%1" == "%2" dotnet pack --no-build --configuration %1 -o ../%3
```

Then, in my project.json, I have:

```
  "scripts": {        
    "postcompile": [
      "makeNuget.cmd %compile:Configuration% Release \\packages\\%project:Name%"
    ]
  }
```

This creates the nuget package and places it in my solution level packages/[project name] folder (though you may need to adjust the relative folder reference in the -o parameter depending on your solution layout).  Also, you don't need the .cmd, by default .cmd is inferred for windows and .sh for other environments.

I also made the target configuration a parameter so that the script is generic and can be used regardless of the configuration name I've chosen as my 'release' config.