# Add Prebuild or Postbuild to dotnet core projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, asp.net-core, .net-core

Is there any way to add prebuild/postbuild options in dotnet core projects in Visual Studio ?

There is no option to add build events in project properties as it used to be with Standard dot net projects [image: standard dot net project properties]

[image: Dot net core projects with no build events option]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37596115/how-to-run-scripts-based-on-solution-configuration-in-asp-net-core-rc2

Comment: I create a demo and test Ricardo Fontana's answer. it works. do you resolve your issue? if not, could you please provide further information?

Comment: @ColeWu yes it solves the problem. Thanks

Comment: If the answer is helpful, please mark it as an answer, It will be very beneficial for other community members who have the similar questions

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example:

```xml
<Project... >
      :
  <Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="echo before" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="echo after" />
  </Target>
      :
</Project>
```

Answer (score 2):

According [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json#scripts), you can add commands, in `scripts` section, in `project.json` file.

```
"scripts": {
    "precompile": [ "echo before" ],
    "postcompile": [ "echo after" ]
}
```