# Asp .Net Core Project.json File

Tags: json, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I am experimenting with creating a .Net Core Project, which is a NETStandard.Library version 1.6.0.

I wanted to experiment with a post build command, but I noticed now that in our project.json file, there is a "postcompile" script that can be created.

Here is the documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json

I have created a .cmd file, that I am calling from the json file like so:

```
"scripts": {
"postcompile": ["copyFiles.cmd"]
```

}

In my cmd file I can have a simple copy command, which works:

```
xcopy /y "C:\Playground\test.txt" "C:\Playground\test\"
```

What I am stuck on, is what variables are now available to me at this point, to give me access to things like the build output directory?  I can't find a reference to this anywhere.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Full list of context variables that you can use to control flow in your scripts is:

Every script block:

```
%project:Directory%
%project:Name%
%project:Version%
```

Compile specific:

```
%compile:TargetFramework%
%compile:FullTargetFramework%
%compile:Configuration%
%compile:OutputFile%
%compile:OutputDir%
%compile:ResponseFile%
%compile:RuntimeOutputDir% (only available if there is runtime output)
%compile:RuntimeIdentifier% (only availabe if there is runtime output)
%comiple:CompilerExitCode% (only available in the postcompile script block)
```

Publish specific:

```
%publish:ProjectPath%
%publish:Configuration%
%publish:OutputPath%
%publish:TargetFramework%
%publish:FullTargetFramework%
%publish:Runtime%
```

References:

https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Project.json-file#scripts

[Post build event depending on configuration name in new ASP.NET 5 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35287635/post-build-event-depending-on-configuration-name-in-new-asp-net-5-project)

Comment: Thank you, that is a very helpful list.  I have noticed that I can get these working if my script is directly within my json file.  However if I put my script into a .cmd file, it no longer seems to know what %compile:OutputDir% is anymore, and my script no longer works. Any clue how to get them working in a cmd file?

Comment: Sorry.. no idea on that

Comment: No I didn't end up getting the cmd file to work unfortunately

Comment: @C.Moore you can pass the `cmd` needed parameters by command line such as `myscript.cmd %compile:OutputDir%` and in the script access them using `$1`,`$2`,...